# Expected time when Brownian motion leaves an interval

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $S_t$ be standard Brownian motion (or a Wiener process) in one dimension. How do I formally derive the expected time that $S_t$ will leave a given interval $[-x, y]$ for some $x, y > 0$, given that $S_0 = 0$?

I suspect that the answer is $xy$ since Brownian motion is the limit of a simple random walk and $xy$ would be the answer for a simple random walk I think, but how do you derive this formally using the definition of a Brownian motion as a limit?

Comment: You are correct. Look at the generator of Brownian motion (similar in spirit to considering a single step of a Random Walk) to yield $$\frac 1 2 \frac {\partial^2 \tau^{x_0}_{x,y}}{\partial x_0^2}=-1$$ plus boundary conditions, yielding $\tau_{x,y}^{x_0}=(y-x_0)(x_0+x)$. You can also argue by simple scaling of BM that $\tau^0_{x,y}\propto xy$.

Comment: In comparison, in the discrete case, analysis of the first step yields: $$\frac 1 2 \delta^2 \tau_{x,y}(x_0)=-1$$ so it's very similar and in the limit $\frac{\delta^2}{h^2}$ becomes ${\partial^2}$.

Comment: Just as a side remark: You can also calculate the expectation using martingale techniques (this leads to Wald's identities).